# can not install app on react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to install an app with react native cli but get the

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in
>   your PATH.
>
> Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
>   location of your Java installation. Could not install the app on the
>   device, read the error above for details. Make sure you have an
>   Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your
>   Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

error...
And frankly this is sooo ofrustrating... Never had an issue with ionic or cordova nor android studio but infortunally, I need some native functions for my app...
Here is a background, at first the app was installing, I even was able to run hot reload on it then out of nowhere, without any change on the computer, I get this message whenever I try :react-native run-android".... I followed exactly what's on facebook github page but got this error... So i tried running a simple app on android studio and it worked... 
Can someone have  solution and also why this is happening out of nowhere?

Oh, I forgot right before I got this error, for some reason, I had to reinstall npm because nodeJs was not recognizing the npm command anymore

Ps : I even uninstall then reinstall android studio, uninstalled react-native-cli and reinstalling it, uninstalled react-native-create-project, reinstalled npm.

Comment: Did u check if u have the same location given to local properties of the react-native app in its Android - local properties file and environmental variables in your system

Comment: How can I check that? and do you know why out of nowhere I get this error? It was working fine before. I even created three apps but all the same error

Comment: Can we see the full console output with the error? Are you pointing to a jdk or a jvm?

Comment: the whole error log is what I posted, i do not have anything more. What's more frustrating is the fact that it was working then out of the blue, this happen

Answer (score 1):

Check like this maybe this is the issue I guess:

1.Open the App that u have created using create-react-native-app or react-native init appName in android studio

It will be something like: appName>android>local properties(SDK location)

2.If u use windows pc/laptop then go to my computer right click for properties>advanced system settings click on that and find the environmental variables

and check if they are matching

Comment: thanks for your response, however, there is no Local properties folder., only app, gradle and keystores

Comment: there will be a folder tell me how u opened it

Comment: It should be a file called local.properties

Comment: do like this open android studio> open folder > then go to ur react native app folder> android then click open in android studio

Comment: there are 4 folders and 6 files, the folders are : .idea, app, gradle and keystores.   the files are :build.gradle, appName.iml, gradle.properties, gradlew, gradlew.bat, local.properties and settings.gradle

Comment: Its in the local.properties file like i said in my other comment

Comment: and in the local properties, the path is : C\:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk

Comment: As @AdarshSreeram said, does this match your path in Environment Variables? For that go to My Computer -> right click it for Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables

Comment: As @AdarshSreeram said, does this match your path in Environment Variables? For that go to My Computer -> right click it for Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables

Comment: @JoaquimAntonioKapel Sorry forgot to tag you. Please see my comment above this one. See if that path matches the path in your environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got tired of it since none of the solutions on the web worked, I just wiped out my computer, reinstalled windows, got rid of all the non needed programs, reinstalled android SDK, java, react and... Still got this error... So I set JAVA_HOME (thanks youtube) and now it is working.

Comment: I told you to check your environment variables. JAVA_HOME is an environment variable. If you did not have that set in the first place, then you would of found this out if you followed my comments correctly

Comment: @ShaneG I did check but I guess I might have installed something I should not because none was working